# Magento2 - Custom Product Type Pricing

Tags: magento2, php

I am working on a custom product type for a Magento2 build that I am working on. I have followed the guide linked below and it has served as a brilliant base for me to work from.

[How to add a new product type in Magento 2? (MageStackDay mystery question 1)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-in-magento-2-magestackday-mystery-question-1)

I am however having trouble in getting the price field show for my custom product type in the admin panel when adding/editing the custom product type and I can not see why, please see image below:

[image]

I think I may missed a price layout/model some where that adds the price field in but can not seem to track down where or what I have missed.

**Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Can you give us some codes / examples that you have tried before to give us a lead to help you ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you do not add you type to list of applicable in price attribute. Add it in install data script:

```
<?php
namespace SuperLLC\SuperType\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];
        $newType = 'super_type';
        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array($newType, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = $newType';
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out today and see where I get to with it.

Comment: Fantastic! More than enough for me to work with. I added the install script and updated field-list and type to what I needed and it worked :). I followed up its behaviour and I understand now why and what I was missing. For anyone that is having missing field issues, it is worth checking the "catalong_eav_aatribute" table, filter by "attribute_id" and check the field "apply_to" to make sure that your new product type is present in the comma separated field.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a quick and dirty solution just add the new product code to the database table

```
catalog_eav_attribute
```

find the "apply_to" column and add the product type code to the list of values