# Magento 2 “customizable” products

Tags: product, magento2, product-attribute

I have a client requesting a webshop where products with "customizable" attributes can be sold. Specifically they will sell fabrics where the buyer can specify a certain length (i.e. 150 cm or 160cm). Also the price must adjust accordingly (i.e. $10 for 150cm and $20 for 300cm).

Is this possible to do with Magento 2? Obviously we couldn't make configurable products with one product for each centimeter. Just a hint on where to start would be super helpful - I really can't find any useful information at all about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at the following starter tutorial for custom products in Magento2

[How to add a new product type in Magento 2? (MageStackDay mystery question 1)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-in-magento-2-magestackday-mystery-question-1)

It worked very well as a starting point for a "grouped configurable" custom product module that I needed to build for my Magneto2 project.

Full credit to Vladimir Kerkhoff