# Why my product type in magento 2 don't have the advanced price?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, product-type

I created special product type. I want to set advanced price but form has no **Advanced price.**

*Simple product*:

[image]

*My special product type*:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please follow. May be you something missing http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-in-magento-2-magestackday-mystery-question-1

Comment: @AnkitShah I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was solved by reinstalling my module with adding base attributes to product type.

```
$attributes = [
    'price',
    'special_price',
    'special_from_date',
    'special_to_date',
    'minimal_price',
    'cost',
    'tier_price',
    'weight',
];
```

[Source](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/custom-product-types-magento-2).